# Managing a data table

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, ado

I have to write a software that manipulates data from a SQL database.

The tables can be huge (> 500,000 lines).

I must manage the display through a table which should be used to display the next lines, above lines, move to the beginning and to the end.

ADO with his Recordset can do that easily with the methods MoveNext, MoveFirst, MovePrevious and MoveLast.

The trouble is that I find that a little slow. Also, for writes (insert, delete, update), I'm already using ADO.NET.

In ADO.NET, we can not handle a real cursor. The only available (through a DataReader) is forwardonly cursor.

I can not load a dataset too because it takes considerable time and memory.

My question is: Does anyone knows a solution to handle this kind of table with ADO.NET?

It is a desktop application, an ERP to be precise.

**Edit:**

I tried to implement the paging system, it works pretty well. However, the results of the ERP applications are **never** sorted by id, I understand that with the paging system, results have to be sorted by ID.

So, if anyone know another method, or how to implement the paging system with this constraint, I'm all ears.

Comment: I think you need to look at the concept of paging.

Comment: What type of application is it (ASP.NET, WebForms, etc.)?

Comment: @Xavinou, I think @JohnFx wasn't talking about the language (C#, VB.NET, F#), but the platform.  Will it run on the web, or is this a desktop application, or something else?

Comment: @JohnFx, it is a desktop application, for an ERP to be precise.

Comment: Well, it has to be sorted by _something_, not necessarily id.  Are the results currently being returned in random order?

Comment: @RQDQ, By reading your comment I think I understood: the criteria for paging in WHERE clause are those of the ORDER BY clause, right ?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? SQL Server?

Comment: @JohnFx: It have to work on SQL Server (2000, 2005, 2008), Oracle 10g and IBM DB2

Comment: @Xavinou - The reason I ask is that you might be able to use a an artificial RowNumber in your query to do the paging without relying on the ID field. However, the implementation of that is going to be different for SQL, Oracle, and DB2.

Comment: @JohnFx : The layer that I'm developing already manages the syntax differences. Everything is already planned and in place). But the priority is clearly SQL Server (used by over 95% of our customers).

Comment: You have a layer that translates between SQL flavors? That's pretty amazing, you should sell it.

Comment: @JohnFx: Yes, but not so great as that. What I do is only possible because developers do not write real SQL, but a pseudo language of our invention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using ADO.NET, you can use a [DataAdapter to fill pages of data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx1c9c2f.aspx) at a time, essentially just what you'd display on the screen.  When you click to the end, it goes and gets exactly the data you need to show that last screen.  It's very fast, and should be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 4):

Try looking at paging... It's the concept of only grabbing that you want to display.

You don't want to use a cursor, because that would require keeping a connection open between requests (generally considered a bad idea in web apps).

Here's something I came across that might help:
http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/efficiently-paging-through-large-amounts-of-data-cs

**EDIT:** Well, the cited example won't be as much help for a desktop application, but the concept of paging is still valid.

Answer (score 2):

The actual implementation will vary depending on the specific technology you are building the app in, but you probably should implement this using a paging strategy.

That is, grab some manageable number of rows at a time (10-50) and display them the user and give the user controls to move to the next/prev page of rows. At no time should you pull down the whole table, since the user is very unlikely to actually every go through all 500K rows in one sitting anyway so pulling them all is a colossal waste of resources and will likely cause major resource contention in your app.